# ReactJS distinguishing clicks from multiple components.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web interface with two buttons:

```
<Panel header="Green Square">
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquareOn}><Glyphicon glyph="ok-circle"/> On</Button>
    <Button bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquareOff}><Glyphicon glyph="remove-circle"/> Off</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
</Panel>
```

and some handling code:

```
handleGreenSquareOn: function() { return this.handleGreenSquare(true); },
handleGreenSquareOff: function() { return this.handleGreenSquare(false); },
handleGreenSuqare: function(value) {
  // do stuff
},
```

What's the best way to eliminate the `handleGreenSquareOn` and `handleGreenSquareOff` functions?

Is there a way of setting an argument for an `onClick` callback in the JSX code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just pass an argument to `handleGreenSquare` like this: 
`onClick={this.handleGreenSquare.bind(this, true)}`

Here is a jsfiddle to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/wsdr48ro/

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Hello = React.createClass({
        handleGreenSquare: function(value) {
          console.log(value);
        },
    render: function() {
        return <ReactBootstrap.Navbar brand="Whoops">
               <ReactBootstrap.Panel header="Green Square">
                     <ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
            <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquare.bind(this, true)}><ReactBootstrap.Glyphicon glyph="ok-circle"/> On</ReactBootstrap.Button>
            <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquare.bind(this, false)}><ReactBootstrap.Glyphicon glyph="remove-circle"/> Off</ReactBootstrap.Button>
          </ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>

            </ReactBootstrap.Panel>
        </ReactBootstrap.Navbar>;
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Hello />, document.body);
```

Comment: I had forgotten that bind could be used for more than just setting `this`.  Excellent answer, thanks.

Comment: This works great, but I recently moved to using a handler generator instead of binding because binding, IMO, looks a bit ugly in the `onClick={}`.  So for example you make a function called `handleClickGenerator` which takes an argument of `foo` and returns a handler function like `return function(e) {...}`.  Then in your JSX just do `onClick={this.handleClickGenerator('bar')} and you can access the var inside the handler function and perform logic, or whatever.

Comment: @Mike that would create a new handler function on each click event wich seems inefficient. Why not re-use one handler and do the logic inside the handler function instead?

Comment: @David we're talking about extremely negligible inefficiency for substantially increased code readability in my opinion.  Also, `.bind()` isn't free either.

Comment: @Mike I agree that `.bind()` is practically the same. I prefer to keep DOM event handlers consistent in all components, because then I don’t have to look around to know how it works. It’s essentially a design decision, as you say.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the handler’s arguments will also remove the event object (unless you pass it manually). I would keep the handlers intact for consistency, but that’s a design choice.

Another options is to add a data attribute and check it inside the handler:

```
handleGreenSquare: function(e) {
  var value = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value') == 'on';
}
```

[...]

```
<Button data-value="on" key="on" bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquare}><Glyphicon glyph="ok-circle"/> On</Button>
<Button data-value="off" key="off" bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquare}><Glyphicon glyph="remove-circle"/> Off</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The callbacks on events will provide the data-reactid as a second variable

So if you alter your function like so:

```
handleGreenSuqare: function(value, reactId) {
  // do stuff with reactId
},
```

you can parse the reactId which are the component keys concatenated by dots.

If you give your button a key attribute like so:

```
<Panel header="Green Square">
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button key="on" bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquareOn}><Glyphicon glyph="ok-circle"/> On</Button>
    <Button key="off" bsStyle="info" onClick={this.handleGreenSquareOff}><Glyphicon glyph="remove-circle"/> Off</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
</Panel>
```

your reactId variable will somewhat look like this for the off button:

```
.0.0.1.0.1.$off
```

inlining the function might be more more expressive, depending on what you are trying to do.

```
<Panel header="Green Square">
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button bsStyle="info" onClick={function() {return this.handleGreenSquare(true);}}><Glyphicon glyph="ok-circle"/> On</Button>
    <Button bsStyle="info" onClick={function() {return this.handleGreenSquare(false);}}><Glyphicon glyph="remove-circle"/> Off</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
</Panel>
```

If you use the es6 harmony features of the jsx compiler, this looks nice and expressive:

```
<Panel header="Green Square">
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button key="on" bsStyle="info" onClick={() => this.handleGreenSquare(true)}><Glyphicon glyph="ok-circle"/> On</Button>
    <Button key="off" bsStyle="info" onClick={() => this.handleGreenSquare(false)}><Glyphicon glyph="remove-circle"/> Off</Button>
  </ButtonToolbar>
</Panel>
```

Comment: Cool, but I wouldn't actually recommend this, and reactid may be going away very soon.

Comment: I fully agree, using a function with .bind or inlining is much better, should have made more clear that it is probably not a smart idea.